# How to get dynamic paint to work in cycles?

Tags: dynamic-paint

So I'm trying out dynamic paint. I set up the scene where a plane passes past a cube. I used the cube as a canvas and the plane as a brush. I generated the UVmap for the cube and  used image sequence on the canvas, and have baked the images. This is how i set up material nodes. [image]

But when I render the image on the viewport, the materials don't change. So I'm not sure what I did wrong?

Comment: Did you test scene in render preview? Often, blender does not update cycles materials in timeline

Comment: I set it up to change material through 30 frames and placed it around frame 25, and then hit Ctrl-z to see if it change material but it didn't. I also tried f12 but didn't change either

Comment: Did you take a look into the dynamic paint sequence? Maybe the baking went wrong? I could imagine, a flat cube would work better as a brush than a plane, but I didn't compare yet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yann! I just check the image sequence they were blank!